# OSSEC - firewall-drop not working for rule 5701

Tags: ids

I am setting up a OSSEC in local mode (on CentOS 7) to act as an IPS for a specific behavior. I am trying to use firewall-drop but it is not working (I noticed that the script can't see **srcip**). let me show you some outputs:

**command:**

```
<command>
    <name>firewall-drop</name>
    <executable>firewall-drop.sh</executable>
    <expect>srcip</expect>
    <timeout_allowed>yes</timeout_allowed>
  </command>
```

**active-response:**

```
<active-response>
    <command>firewall-drop</command>
    <location>local</location>
    <rules_id>5701</rules_id>
    <timeout>86400</timeout>
  </active-response>
```

**ossec-logtest output:**

```
**Phase 1: Completed pre-decoding.
       full event: 'Jul 11 16:15:50 cloud sshd[31119]: Bad protocol version identification 'POST http://muabannha.org/ HTTP/1.1' from 45.32.161.230 port 53595'
       hostname: 'cloud'
       program_name: 'sshd'
       log: 'Bad protocol version identification 'POST http://muabannha.org/ HTTP/1.1' from 45.32.161.230 port 53595'

**Phase 2: Completed decoding.
       decoder: 'sshd'

**Phase 3: Completed filtering (rules).
       Rule id: '5701'
       Level: '8'
       Description: 'Possible attack on the ssh server (or version gathering).'
**Alert to be generated.
```

any clue?

Thanks in advance,
:wq!

Comment: The rule_id 5706 works perfectly without any change: https://hastebin.com/leleqarape.pl

I can't understand why!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug,

I found and fixed it then sent a pull request to OSSEC team: https://github.com/ossec/ossec-hids/pull/1194

I had to change the ssh-scan decoder. In fact it was needed to split ssh-scan2 into two different regex. The change can be found [here](https://github.com/ossec/ossec-hids/commit/e0387eca35d59c953d2045457d327fba3c3b9091).

Thanks,